# Covariance and contravariance on example

Tags: c#, delegates, contravariance

I've created a hierarchy of classes like Object->MyClass->MyDerivedClass:

```
class MyClass : object
    {
        public string MyMethod()
        {
            return "My method called";
        }
    }

class MyDerivedClass : MyClass
{
    public string MyDerivedMethod()
    {
        return "My Derived method called";
    }
}
```

Now in the code I declare a Func and try to assign a delegate to it

```
Func<MyClass, string> myFunc = delegate(object a) { return ""; };
```

In .NET `Func` is declared as

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

Thus that first `in T` parameter is contravariant. And according to MSDN

> Contravariance enables you to use a less derived type than that
>   specified by the generic parameter

So I can assign `object` as a parameter instead of `MyClass`. If so, why do I get the "incompatible signature error" error?

And even if I change my assignment as

```
Func<MyClass, string> myFunc = delegate(MyDerivedClass a) { return ""; };
```

I'm still getting the same `"incompatible signature error" error`.

Comment: For completeness, maybe you should include the compiler error in full.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot convert anonymous method to delegate type 'System.Func<ConsoleApplication1.MyClass,string>' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types

Comment: Error 2 Parameter 1 is declared as type 'object' but should be 'ConsoleApplication1.MyClass'