# Contravariant delegate output result

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance

I defined my class hierarchy as Object->Fruit->Apple

```
class Fruit : object{}

class Apple : Fruit{}
```

And created two static methods to work with these classes

```
    static Fruit FruitProcessor(string fruit)
    {
        return new Fruit();
    }

    static Apple ApplesProcessor(string apple)
    {
        return new Apple();
    }
```

Now I declare a delegate **without any** `in, out` keywords

```
public delegate TResult Funk<T, TResult>(T arg);
```

And in my code I do the following assignment:

```
        Funk<string, Fruit> myFunc;
        myFunc = FruitProcessor; // ok, we match signature exactly
        myFunc = ApplesProcessor;// this should not work, but works
```

Since I did not declare TResult as covariant `out` parameter it should not be possible to assign `ApplesProcessor` to `myFunc` delegate. But it is possible, program compiles and executes without any errors.

And if I change Funk signature to add `out TResult`

```
public delegate TResult Funk<T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

Everything works in the same way as before.

How is it possible?

Comment: Isn't this pretty much [what you asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922464/covariance-and-contravariance-on-example), but using methods rather than lambdas?  I think both of these were covered in the question that was linked as a duplicate...? IE if you're using a lambda, you *can* make the signature match, so you *must* make it match?  But for methods, that's not enforced?

Comment: This is a slightly different question. The previous one was about special interpretation of antonymous functions. This one seems to be caused by .NET 3.5 changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case like this is handled by the usual implicit conversion. Quoting the relevant MSDN page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx):

```
public class First { }
public class Second : First { }
public delegate First SampleDelegate(Second a);
public delegate R SampleGenericDelegate<A, R>(A a);

// Matching signature. 
public static First ASecondRFirst(Second first)
{ return new First(); }

// The return type is more derived. 
public static Second ASecondRSecond(Second second)
{ return new Second(); }

// The argument type is less derived. 
public static First AFirstRFirst(First first)
{ return new First(); }

// The return type is more derived  
// and the argument type is less derived. 
public static Second AFirstRSecond(First first)
{ return new Second(); }

// Assigning a method with a matching signature  
// to a non-generic delegate. No conversion is necessary.
SampleDelegate dNonGeneric = ASecondRFirst;
// Assigning a method with a more derived return type  
// and less derived argument type to a non-generic delegate. 
// The implicit conversion is used.
SampleDelegate dNonGenericConversion = AFirstRSecond;

// Assigning a method with a matching signature to a generic delegate. 
// No conversion is necessary.
SampleGenericDelegate<Second, First> dGeneric = ASecondRFirst;
// Assigning a method with a more derived return type  
// and less derived argument type to a generic delegate. 
// The implicit conversion is used.
SampleGenericDelegate<Second, First> dGenericConversion = AFirstRSecond;
```

In short, in your exact case, you are assigning a non-generic delegate to a generic delegate - the implicit conversion is always used in that case. To actually make your code fail, you need to do something like this:

```
Funk<string, Fruit> myFunc;
Funk<string, Apple> myAppleFunc = ApplesProcessor;
myFunc = FruitProcessor;
myFunc = myAppleFunc; // Undefined implicit conversion on generic delegate
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx) covariance for delegate return types and contravariance for delegate input types is implied since .NET 3.5.  So adding `in` and `out` to your delegate makes no difference.

One reason this was added was so that you could assign a "vanilla" event handler that accepts an `EventArgs` parameter to multiple events that may use more specific classes that derive from `EventArgs`.  For example you can use the same delegate to handle a button click and a key press, even though the former passes a `MouseEventArgs` parameter while the latter passes a `KeyEventArgs` parameter.

Comment: But `in` or `out` can not be different with default behavior. If you make argument `out`, you will get compiler error. You can ether make it `in`, or leave it as it is and it will be treated like `in` by default.